# $G$ abelian. If $G\cong \sum G_i$ then $mG \cong \sum mG_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $G\cong \sum_{i \in I} G_i$, then $mG \cong \sum_{i \in I} mG_i$.

$$\sum_{i \in I} G_i = \{ f:I\rightarrow \cup G_i \mid f(i) \in G_i \text{ and } f(i)=e_i \text{ for all but finitely many $i$}\}$$

I know that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an injective homomorphism of groups and if $A \leq X$ then $A \cong f(A)$. In the first part of the problem we showed that if $G$ is abelian then $mG \leq G$. $G$ is abelian so $mG\trianglelefteq G$.

I was magically hoping that somehow if I took $f:G\rightarrow \sum_{i\in I}G_i$ to be an isomorphism of groups that since we have $mG \cong f(mG)$ that it would happen to be that
$$f(mG)=\sum_{i \in I} mG_i.$$
It doesn't look apparent and may not be true so I was thinking of if I could do some kind of composition of maps and use that isomorphism $f$ that I am given. What is a direction I could try to head in to get the answer?

Comment: I would think the claim $f(mG)=\sum_{i\in I}mG_i$ is true and can be verified pretty straightforwardly. You just have to have in mind that $mg$ is equal to $g$ added $m$ times and that the isomorphism preserves sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the advice of PavelC:

We have $f:G\rightarrow \sum_{i\in I}G_i$, an isomorphism of groups. As I said in my question, we know that $mG \cong f(mG)$.
$$f(mG)=\{f(mg)\mid g \in G\} =\{ \underbrace{f(g)+f(g)+\dots+f(g)}_{m \text{ times}} \mid g \in G\} =\{mf(g)\mid g\in G\}.$$

If $(a_i)_{i\in I} \in f(mG)$, $(a_i)_{i \in I} = mf(g)$ for some $g \in G$. Call $f(g)=(b_i)_{i \in I}$.
$$(a_i)_{i \in I}=mf(g)=m(b_i)_{i \in I}=(mb_i)_{i \in I}$$
and so each $a_i=mb_i \in mG_i$ for all $i \in I$ and $a_i=e_i$ for all but finitely many $I$ as $(a_i)_{i \in I} \in \sum_{i\in I} G_i$. We have then $(a_i)_{i \in I} \in \sum_{i \in I} mG_i$.
If we pick $(mg_i)_{i\in I}\in\sum_{i\in I} mG_i$ then
$$(mg_i)_{i\in I}=\underbrace{(g_i)_{i \in I}+\dots+(g_i)_{i \in I}}_{m \text{ times}}=m(g_i)_{i \in I}=mf(g)$$
for some $g \in G$, as $f$ is surjective, so $(mg_i)_{i\in I} \in f(mG)$.